# logistic regression in R for a list of SNPs to get summary statistics

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I want to run a regression for a case-control outcome/disease (0,1 format for controls and cases) for a list of 30 SNPs (single nucleotide polymorphisms in 0, 1, 2 format for genotypes). I know how to do it for one SNP using following in R;

`test = glm(casecontrol ~ rs12345, data=mydata, family=binomial)`

Question: How do I run a model to get a summary statistics for an association of 30 SNPs with the disease in one go in R? Something like we get from GWAS, beta estimates, p values, SD, allele frequencies? Any package in R that I can use?

EDIT:

````
structure(list(ID = 1:6, sex = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), age = c(49.65, 
48.56, 49.55, 55.23, 60.62, 60.19), bmi = c(18.09, 22.82, 31.31, 
21.87, 30.07, 26.75), casecontrol = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    rs1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), rs2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), rs3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs4 = c(1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), rs5 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), rs6 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs7 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs8 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs9 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), rs10 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs11 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs12 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), rs13 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), rs14 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs16 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), rs17 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs18 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), rs19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), rs20 = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs21 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L), rs22 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs23 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), rs24 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), rs25 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs26 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rs27 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs28 = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L), rs29 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), rs30 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: Would you mind sharing a small snippet of your data? dput(head(mydata)) please.

Comment: @ChuckP The original data is in collaboration with another institute and even I'm not allowed to bring it out of their server. Is it ok if I make some similar dummy data and share?

Comment: Yes please I don't need to see much see much just mainly the structure of the dataframe how many columns for example, are there more columns than just the outcome and the 30 SNPs.

Comment: @ChuckP I have added the 'dput(head(mydata))' output as an edit to my question above. data have other columns like ID, age, sex, bmi along with outcome (casecontrol) and data for 30 SNPs. If it doesn't suffice I can share the dummy file I've made. I also have a choice to only keep 'outcome' and SNPs data while analysing, but ID column would stay.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know give me a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.  Using multiple predictors is as simple as adding them in one by one... So to just practice on the first 3 change the command as shown (more in a minute on making that easy with 30 predictors.

**EDITED** to make sure we convert the SNPs to factors as opposed to integers assuming they are factors. Also a better toy dataset that converges

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

glm(casecontrol ~ as.factor(rs1) + as.factor(rs2) + as.factor(rs3), data = mydata, family=binomial)
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = casecontrol ~ as.factor(rs1) + as.factor(rs2) + 
#>     as.factor(rs3), family = binomial, data = mydata)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>     (Intercept)  as.factor(rs1)1  as.factor(rs1)2  as.factor(rs2)1  
#>         0.03811          0.13198         -0.20161          0.22642  
#> as.factor(rs2)2  as.factor(rs3)1  as.factor(rs3)2  
#>         0.10170         -0.22889         -0.03697  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 499 Total (i.e. Null);  493 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       693 
#> Residual Deviance: 688.4     AIC: 702.4
```

Use the `summary` command to get p values etc.

```
summary(glm(casecontrol ~ as.factor(rs1) + as.factor(rs2) + as.factor(rs3), data = mydata, family=binomial))
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = casecontrol ~ as.factor(rs1) + as.factor(rs2) + 
#>     as.factor(rs3), family = binomial, data = mydata)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
#> -1.350  -1.193   1.014   1.161   1.348  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)      0.03811    0.22619   0.168    0.866
#> as.factor(rs1)1  0.13198    0.22276   0.592    0.554
#> as.factor(rs1)2 -0.20161    0.22264  -0.906    0.365
#> as.factor(rs2)1  0.22642    0.22111   1.024    0.306
#> as.factor(rs2)2  0.10170    0.21969   0.463    0.643
#> as.factor(rs3)1 -0.22889    0.21864  -1.047    0.295
#> as.factor(rs3)2 -0.03697    0.22117  -0.167    0.867
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 693.02  on 499  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 688.39  on 493  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 702.39
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

Better yet use `broom::tidy` to get nice output

```r
tidy(glm(casecontrol ~ as.factor(rs1) + as.factor(rs2) + as.factor(rs3), data = mydata, family=binomial))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   term            estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)       0.0381     0.226     0.168   0.866
#> 2 as.factor(rs1)1   0.132      0.223     0.592   0.554
#> 3 as.factor(rs1)2  -0.202      0.223    -0.906   0.365
#> 4 as.factor(rs2)1   0.226      0.221     1.02    0.306
#> 5 as.factor(rs2)2   0.102      0.220     0.463   0.643
#> 6 as.factor(rs3)1  -0.229      0.219    -1.05    0.295
#> 7 as.factor(rs3)2  -0.0370     0.221    -0.167   0.867
```

Obviously with example data we won't get real answers.

To be most efficient of your time create a temporary data set for analysis.  We'll call it `justanalyze` that contains just the outcome and variables you actually want to use.  Then we can use `casecontrol ~ .` to say casecontrol with everything else as a predictor.

```r
justanalyze <- 
  mydata %>% 
  select(casecontrol, rs1:rs30) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(rs1:rs30), as.factor)

# glm(casecontrol ~ ., data = justanalyze, family=binomial)
# summary(glm(casecontrol ~ ., data = justanalyze, family=binomial))
tidy(glm(casecontrol ~ ., data = justanalyze, family=binomial))
#> # A tibble: 61 x 5
#>    term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 (Intercept) -0.493       0.782  -0.630    0.529 
#>  2 rs11         0.143       0.249   0.574    0.566 
#>  3 rs12        -0.157       0.244  -0.642    0.521 
#>  4 rs21         0.106       0.248   0.428    0.669 
#>  5 rs22         0.0427      0.243   0.176    0.860 
#>  6 rs31        -0.231       0.238  -0.970    0.332 
#>  7 rs32         0.00169     0.245   0.00690  0.994 
#>  8 rs41        -0.259       0.244  -1.06     0.288 
#>  9 rs42        -0.474       0.253  -1.87     0.0610
#> 10 rs51         0.0148      0.256   0.0577   0.954 
#> # … with 51 more rows
```

Better made up data (example)

```r
set.seed(2020)
mydata <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, 
                     sex = sample(1:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE), 
                     age = runif(100, min= 35, max = 70), 
                     bmi = runif(100, min= 15, max = 35), 
                     casecontrol = sample(0:1, size = 500, replace = TRUE), 
                     rs1 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE), 
                     rs2 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs3 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs4 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs5 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs6 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs7 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs8 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs9 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs10 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs11 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs12 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs13 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs14 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs15 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs16 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs17 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs18 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs19 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs20 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs21 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs22 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs23 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs24 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs25 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs26 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs27 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs28 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs29 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE),
                     rs30 = sample(0:2, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
)

# mydata
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @Chuck P. I have been looking for a solution since a while and at last something so clear. Bless you :)

Comment: No problem, if those SNP values are to be treated as factors make sure you change them otherwise they will be treated as real integers rather than contrasts.

Comment: Thank you. You're amazing... I understand that I have to keep them as factors. But what if we have any other figures than 0,1,2. For example, sometimes machine reading for genotype ends up in figures like 0.001, 0.999 & 1.999 (instead of 0,1,2). Can we still use as.factor for such figures and fit the model successfully?

Comment: Yes what you have will work.  As long as they are factors meaning that you don't want to treat them as numbers.  Your tidy output for such an SNP (for example `rs1` would look like `rs10.001     -0.385      0.289    -1.33    0.183
 rs10.999     -0.431      0.283    -1.53    0.127
 rs11.999     -0.483      0.295    -1.64    0.102`